# Filtering in DJANGO with OR condition

Tags: python, django, rest, filter, django-rest-framework

I have a restfull API created with Django and DRF. When I try to filter with OR condition (), it doesn't detect the condition and return all the objects. I want to make it work by a diferent way other than modifying the "get_queryset" method.

I want to find the way to implement some module or backend filter package to implement that filters

Comment: you need to share more details for community to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be realized by using `Q` objects, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

For example, suppose you have a model `User` with a `CharField` `type`:

```py
User.objects.filter(
    Q(type="admin") | Q(type="moderator")
)
```

would return all `User` objects where `type` is either `admin` or `moderator`.